# Determining ascii character in NSString

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uikeyinput

In one of my `UIView` classes, I have the `UIKeyInput` protocol attached to gather input from a `UIKeyboard`. I'm trying to figure out what ascii character is being used when the space button is pushed (it's not simply ' ' it's something else it appears). Does anyone know what this asci character is or how I can figure out what ascii code is being used?

Comment: Space in ASCII is `' '` or 0x20 (32 decimal).

Comment: You shouldn't be looking for ASCII characters. Users type in Unicode characters in iOS. Of course ASCII values 0-127 are the same as the Unicode characters \U0000 - \U007F.

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To look at the value for each character you can do something like this:

```
NSString *text = ... // the text to examine
for (NSUInteger c = 0; c < text.length; c++) {
    unichar char = [text characterAtIndex:c];
    NSLog(@"char = %x", (int)char); // Log the hex value of the Unicode character
}
```

Please note that this code doesn't properly handle any Unicode characters in the range \U10000 and up. This includes many (all?) of the Emoji characters.

Answer (score 1):

If you *really* need to know what character (or code point) it actually is, use the `CFMutableString` function `CFStringTransform()`
That enables you to use transformation argument `kCFStringTransformToUnicodeName` to get the human readable Unicode name for example or `Hex-Any` to get escaped Unicode code point.

Otherwise you can do the the `unichar` approach to simple get the code point.